# Cloudbees Deploy failure due to NullPointerException in RunTargetImpl.getClickStackConfigMap

Tags: cloudbees

I've juste created an new app in cloudbees  with clickStart "Jetty 9 Embedded App"  and when Jenkins build the generated project(without any change) I get this error.

Can you help me to find the problem origin ?

thanks.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.919s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 27 06:49:44 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/40M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /scratch/jenkins/workspace/code-elevator-2/pom.xml to /home/flagadajones/hudson_home/jobs/code-elevator-2/modules/localdomain.localhost$jetty9-embedded-clickstart/builds/2013-09-27_10-48-58/archive/localdomain.localhost/jetty9-embedded-clickstart/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jetty9-embedded-clickstart-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /scratch/jenkins/workspace/code-elevator-2/target/jetty9-embedded-clickstart-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/flagadajones/hudson_home/jobs/code-elevator-2/modules/localdomain.localhost$jetty9-embedded-clickstart/builds/2013-09-27_10-48-58/archive/localdomain.localhost/jetty9-embedded-clickstart/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jetty9-embedded-clickstart-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /scratch/jenkins/workspace/code-elevator-2/target/jetty9-embedded-clickstart-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar to /home/flagadajones/hudson_home/jobs/code-elevator-2/modules/localdomain.localhost$jetty9-embedded-clickstart/builds/2013-09-27_10-48-58/archive/localdomain.localhost/jetty9-embedded-clickstart/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jetty9-embedded-clickstart-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
channel stopped
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying as (jenkins) to the flagadajones account
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying code-elevator-2
[cloudbees-deployer]   Resolved from archived artifacts as /home/flagadajones/hudson_home/jobs/code-elevator-2/modules/localdomain.localhost$jetty9-embedded-clickstart/builds/2013-09-27_10-48-58/archive/localdomain.localhost/jetty9-embedded-clickstart/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jetty9-embedded-clickstart-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.exceptions.DeployException
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl.newDeployActor(RunEngineImpl.java:150)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl.newDeployActor(RunEngineImpl.java:52)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.process(Engine.java:173)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.perform(Engine.java:112)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:103)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:812)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:784)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:957)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:734)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1600)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:485)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunTargetImpl.getClickStackConfigMap(RunTargetImpl.java:256)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl$DeployFileCallable.<init>(RunEngineImpl.java:297)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl.newDeployActor(RunEngineImpl.java:141)
    ... 13 more
Build step 'Deploy applications' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

The clickstart generates an invalid configuration for the deployer plugin. Remove the target from the deploy publisher and add it back again. The issue is that the Maven artifact selector is not selected and the clickstart has fed incorrect configuration for the target, which means that you can't just select the maven artifact selector, instead you need to remove the target and add it back again...

Nuts I know, I shall be chastising the clickstart maintainers on Monday rest assured ;-)